# JSON-LD framing one object to multiple references

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, json-ld

In my example I have one entity with two labels. Each labels has a reference to a language object:

```
[
  {
    "@id": "http://example.com/entity",
    "http://example.com/label": [
      {
        "@id": "http://example.com/label1"
      },
      {
        "@id": "http://example.com/label2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "@id": "http://example.com/label1",
    "http://example.com/value": "Label 1",
    "http://example.com/language": {
      "@id": "http://example.com/language"
    }
  },
  {
    "@id": "http://example.com/label2",
    "http://example.com/value": "Label 2",
    "http://example.com/language": {
      "@id": "http://example.com/language"
    }
  },
  {
    "@id": "http://example.com/language",
    "http://example.com/value": "English"
  }
]
```

When I parse it with a following frame:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@base": "http://example.com/",
    "@vocab": "http://example.com/"
  },
  "@graph": {
    "label": {}
  }
}
```

I get the "English" value only in one of the labels. The second one has only the language id:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@base": "http://example.com/",
    "@vocab": "http://example.com/"
  },
  "@id": "entity",
  "label": [
    {
      "@id": "label1",
      "language": {
        "@id": "language",
        "value": "English"
      },
      "value": "Label 1"
    },
    {
      "@id": "label2",
      "language": {
        "@id": "language"
      },
      "value": "Label 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a way I could have the "English" value in both of my labels?

My example is available on [json-ld playground](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-framed&json-ld=%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fentity%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Flabel%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Flabel1%22%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Flabel2%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Flabel1%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fvalue%22%3A%22Label%201%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Flanguage%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Flanguage%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Flabel2%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fvalue%22%3A%22Label%202%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Flanguage%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Flanguage%22%7D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Flanguage%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fvalue%22%3A%22English%22%7D%5D&frame=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22%40base%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%22%2C%22%40vocab%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%22%7D%2C%22%40graph%22%3A%7B%22label%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%7D).

Comment: Try `"@embed": "@always"`.

Comment: @StanislavKralin thanks!
Puting the `"@embed": "@always"` in a `label` helped :).
Please, add a solution and I'll approve it.